# Negative INNER JOIN [Without LEFT JOIN & IS NULL]

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 2 tables with tth hashes, and i need to get which of them, who exist in first table but not exist in second table.
I'll try something like this:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM files as f
LEFT JOIN trans as t ON t.tth=f.tth
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

But it's working very slow, in first table 65k lines, and second table with 130k lines, so query working for ~5 minutes. 
Here exist another way?
Thanks.

P.S. All columns in both tables having indexes.

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/

Comment: You don't need to create indexes on all columns. I believe t.id is primary. Just create index on tth column of both tables.

Comment: Oops, I meant the columns involved in the request.

Comment: What happens if you change the last line to: `WHERE t.tth IS NULL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, [OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies), I read an article on the link, and a little optimizing method using NOT IN, query rate was ~ 0.6 seconds.

```
    SELECT f.*
    FROM files as f
    WHERE 
    f.tth NOT IN (
      SELECT trans.tth
      FROM trans as t
-- We do not need to look entries across entire table, only from already matched, so create selection "limits" with INNER JOIN.
      INNER JOIN files ON files.tth=t.tth
    )
```

Comment: this is true for the moment, but when the intersection between trans and files will grow this is going to become the contrary I think.

Comment: Yes, in the worst case. This solution is only for specific data.
If anything, we should keep in mind where we can remove one line from query.